# How to disable crash dumps programatically in c++?

Tags: c++, c

I'm writing a unit test application, where I want to make one of the methods to fail. For this I'm passing a NULL parameter to the method. But this is causing crash dump in the downstream. So how can we disable the crash dump generation through code?

I'm expecting there will be some registry setting for this, which can be changed through code.

Comment: Needs more information, operating system for a start.

Comment: Then the test works, because it found a bug. Fix the bug (i.e. check foir `NULL` pointers and return a failure) instead of work around it. Even if you disable "crash dumps" the crash will still happen otherwise.

Comment: Seems more reasonable to ask "how do I control where the crashdump ends up, so I can delete it", or something along those lines - if the code crashes, you may indeed want a crashdump to figure out what happened.

Comment: Why do you want your program to crash? Usually, unfulfilled preconditions in a function call lead to undefined behavior. In this case, the program is allowed to crash when an invalid function call is made, but it is nothing that must be tested.

Comment: You would do this with the setrlimit() call - which only affects the current process (and it's child processes). But you are talking about some "downstream", so perhaps disabling core files for the current process isn't what you need. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think the requirement here is incorrect. There are few signals which cannot be caught by the program itself. SIGSEGV ( which is raised when you access invalid memory / NULL ) is one among them. No operating system would expose an interface where you can control a SIGSEGV at the programs will. That would be very poor OS design.

It is best to rewrite the unit test which should just check for values ( as suggested by Joachim ), not crash the application. Crash tests come under system testing, and is not within the scope of unit testing.

Comment: incorrect. SIGSEGV is catchable on linux. Though, one of the reasons of assigning signal handler for SIGSEGV is to print a "backtrace" of the crash.

Comment: SIGSEGV is only catchable for linux kernels with the grsecurity patches applied, John.  That means it is not available under all distributions.